# Where to write controllers code in MVC architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, mern

I have a problem in writing and determining controllers code in MVC architecture for a project I am working on.

I am developing a job recruitment app, consider a linked in clone, I am using mern stack, finished writing the architecture, and currently implementing the API.

My problem specifically occurs when determining the controllers, should each model has its own controller with its own crud operations?
To make the question clearer, an employer creates a job listing, should the logic of creation a job listing be inside the employer controller knowing that the employer references the job listing with a one-to-many relation, or make a separate job listing controller with separate crud operations, and pass the employer as a reference from the request? And how would that affect the implementation in the front end?

I tried to create the job listing inside the employer controller, and tried to create a job listing controller but couldn't get how would that affect the db reference in the model.